# Accelerated game time with TimeSpan in C#

Tags: c#, dispatchertimer

I need to create an accelerated game time (presumably using a DispatcherTimer). I want 1 minute of 'real time' to equal 10 minutes of 'game time'.

Also, how would I set up gametime? Would this be a DateTime object? For example, let's say the game starts at 0600. Every 6 seconds I want the game time to increase by one minute.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameTime is more likely to be a TimeSpan object which starts at zero and increments by as many seconds as you want by using its Add method. You would add 60 seconds to the TimeSpan object every time your "real world timer" registers a change of 6 seconds. Presumably you'd want to set your "real world timer" object up to notify you when each 6000ms has passed.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Quick question: how do I set GameTime (which is a TimeSpan object) to a specific start time (say 0625)?

Comment: The constructor is; TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(hh,mm,ss). So in your case TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(6,25,0);

Comment: Thanks, again! Works a charm!